# Problem with passing SOAP headers using Apache CXF client

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I am trying to implement a simple client for a webservice, the only problem I am facing with the webservice is, it has a generic endpoint: `http://myserver3333.com:8080/ws/services` and the way you lookup for web services deployed is via SOAP header.

So, for example, if you try to hit the service vis SOAP UI,

1. the endpoint I specify is: `http://myserver3333.com:8080/ws/services`
2. In the SOAP headers I specific the following:
   SERVICE-NAME = MyAwesomeService
   OPERATION-NAME = makeMeMoreAwesome

So, how can I do the same thing using apache cxf client?

My current code:

```
    URL wsdlLocation = new URL("http://myserver3333.com:8080/ws/service");

    MyAwesomeService  service = new MyAwesomeService(wsdlLocation);
    MyAwesomeServicePort port = service.getMyAwesomeServiceSOAPPort();

    List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();
    Header operationNameHeader = new Header(new QName("OPERATION-NAME"), "makeMeMoreAwesome",
                                            new JAXBDataBinding(String.class));
    Header serviceNameHeader = new Header(new QName("SERVICE-NAME"), "MyAwesomeService",
                                            new JAXBDataBinding(String.class));

    headers.add(operationNameHeader);
    headers.add(serviceNameHeader);

    BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider)port;
    bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(Header.HEADER_LIST, headers);

    MakeMeMoreAwesomeRequest request = new MakeMeMoreAwesomeRequest();
    MakeMeMoreAwesomeResponse response = port.makeMeMoreAwesome(request);

    System.out.println(response.getAck());
```

But when I run this, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.InaccessibleWSDLException: 2 counts of InaccessibleWSDLException.

java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://myserver3333.com:8080/ws/services
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://myserver3333.com:8080/ws/services?wsdl
```

Which is correct because there is no WSDL at that location, it need to follow the soap header to get the service.

Update:

After two points from @Daniel Kulp I am here:

1. I added a new line: `bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "http://myserver3333.com:8080/ws/services");`

And now I get this error:

```
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: "http://www.myserver.com/ws/services", the namespace on the "errorMessage" element, is not a valid SOAP version.
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.readVersion(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:141)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:771)
```

My assumption is, this error is same as [this](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-users/200807.mbox/%3C18227463.post@talk.nabble.com%3E) one. But I am not using ?wsdl. So, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 comments:

1) You aren't picking up CXF.  Check your classpath to make sure CXF is there and not the Sun/Oracle implementation.   com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.InaccessibleWSDLException shows you are picking up the Sun implementation.

2) The URL passed into MyAwesomeService(wsdlLocation) MUST be a URL to the WSDL, not the endpoint itself.

Comment: I see, when I import `import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider` I get this warning: Access restriction: The type BindingProvider is not accessible due to restriction on required library C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar. It's only a warning, but why am I getting that? What is the alternative to that?

Comment: Yes.  You may want to turn on the Logging stuff to see the payloads.  It looks like you are getting a generic error page back from the server (maybe a 404?), not a SOAP message.

Comment: I got the answer to my problem, the problem was the service did not support soap headers, but http headers!!!